# Does anyone have an example of using sprite sheets in tandem with XML files

Tags: python, xml, pygame

Ok, so i have a sprite sheet, and the position of all of the sprites listed in an xml file shown below:

```
<TextureAtlas imagePath="walkRight.png">
    <SubTexture name="walkRightIdle.png" x="0" y="0" width="22" height = "28"/>
    <SubTexture name="walkRight1.png" x="22" y="0" width = "22" height = "28"/>
    <SubTexture name="walkRight2.png" x="44" y="0" width = "22" height = "28"/>
</TextureAtlas>
```

So what i am wondering is how i can select which image to use within python, for example, if i wanted to use the sprite "walkRight1.png" how would I go about assigning that to a tangible thing in pygame, so i can take that - import the x and y axis, the width and height and use that to select the part of the spritesheet i'd like to use.

not sure if this makes sense, trying to parse xml in python in the way that i want makes my head hurt.

Comment: Have you tried something so far? If you provide your current programming effort along with specific problem description, you are much more likely to get answers.

Comment: Yes, i used the official docs but only managed to get it to print the children parts, not place the individual parts within their own sections

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could share that code and specifically tell how it works incorrectly. The question as such is somewhat too open-ended.

Comment: it's not not working, i just dont know how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We use Kenny.nl art packs in class all the time, and they usually come with XML like your example.  Here's how we do it, by parsing the xml into a dictionary:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

class SpriteSheet:
    # load an atlas image
    # can also pass an associated XML file (ref. Kenney art)
    def __init__(self, img_file, data_file=None):
        self.spritesheet = pg.image.load(img_file).convert_alpha()
        if data_file:
            tree = ET.parse(data_file)
            self.map = {}
            for node in tree.iter():
                if node.attrib.get('name'):
                    name = node.attrib.get('name')
                    self.map[name] = {}
                    self.map[name]['x'] = int(node.attrib.get('x'))
                    self.map[name]['y'] = int(node.attrib.get('y'))
                    self.map[name]['width'] = int(node.attrib.get('width'))
                    self.map[name]['height'] = int(node.attrib.get('height'))

    def get_image_rect(self, x, y, w, h):
        return self.spritesheet.subsurface(pg.Rect(x, y, w, h))

    def get_image_name(self, name):
        rect = pg.Rect(self.map[name]['x'], self.map[name]['y'],
                       self.map[name]['width'], self.map[name]['height'])
        return self.spritesheet.subsurface(rect)
```

Load the spritesheet and xml file (if you have one) like this:

```
sheet = SpriteSheet("sheet.png", "sheet.xml")
```

Then you can cut out images by name or by dimensions:

```
img1 = sheet.get_image_name("walkRightIdle.png")
img2 = sheet.get_image_rect(0, 0, 22, 28)
```

Note there's no error checking or anything, so it's assuming you're using the XML format a la Kenny.nl art.